# Java - How to Access Values from an ArrayList containing Generic Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a generic ArrayList that contains different types of arrays. I need to loop through each element of the inner arrays and access them. However, I'm not sure how to access the inner array elements due to the use of generics.

Once I have the array from the first loop of the ArrayList, how can I access each element?

This is a simplified version of what I have:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Object[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer[] a1 = {1,2,3,4};
        String[] a2 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        Double[] a3 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
        arrList.add(a1);
        arrList.add(a2);
        arrList.add(a3);

        printList(arrList);
    }

    public static <E> void printList(ArrayList<E> arrList) {
        for (E arr : arrList) {
            for (E elm : arr) {
                System.out.println(elm);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ``if (arr.getClass().isArray()) { for(Object o : (Object[]) arr) {`` Addenda: there is ``Arrays#deepToString`` to help print a multidimensional array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that, within the body of the method, the compiler doesn't know that `E` is an array. `E` could be a String, an Integer, or anything else. Nested loops are not possible because they wouldn't apply to these cases.

You can use `ArrayList<E[]>` instead of `ArrayList<E>` in the method declaration to make this method only apply to arrays. When we do this, `E` resolves to `Object` rather than `Object[]`:

```
public static <E> void printList(ArrayList<E[]> arrList) {
    for (E[] arr : arrList) {
        for (E elm : arr) {
            System.out.println(elm);
        }

    }
}
```

If you are only passing `arrList` (which is of type `ArrayList<Object[]>`) to this method, it doesn't need to be generic. You could just make it accept `ArrayList<Object[]>` instead.

```
public static void printList(ArrayList<Object[]> arrList) {
    for (Object[] arr : arrList) {
        for (Object elm : arr) {
            System.out.println(elm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not assume to have an array of a generic. Type generic can be an array of its own. I would prefer some kind of ``if (arr.getClass().isArray())`` handling.

Comment: @spi The reason I wrote it this way is because I think the intention of the OP is to create a method that can print an array list of arrays, instead of any old array list.

Comment: Just curious. To add an Integer[], String[] and Double[], the initial ArrayList the type has to be declared as `ArrayList<Object[]>` right? Or is there some other way of adding it?

Comment: @BlackPearl The most specific type you can use is `Object[]`, but you can always go less specific i.e. `Object`.

Comment: But, for the 1st piece of code to work, it has to be specified as Object[] right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BlackPearl Yes.

Answer (score 1):

See

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrList.toArray()));
```

for easy and quick print of a multidimensional array.